# Mascara ou formatar valor em input no angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Como eu posso fazer para formatar ou usar mascaras em inputs com o angular2, como por exemplo para dinheiro

Neste input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm text-right" id="representPercDiagnostico" 
                    placeholder="DIAGNÓSTICO"
                    required [(ngModel)]="questionario3.RepresentPercDiagnostico" (blur)="somaValores()">
```

Se o usuario digitar um valor ele vai aparecer da forma digitada, mas eu gostaria que  aparece formatado, por exemplo: se o usuario digitar 205.5 eu gostaria que aparecesse  205,50.

Em outros casos também usar mascaras para numeros de telefone, por exemplo: (00)12345678.

Comment: Procure por [Filter do Angular JS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), [aqui os tipos default](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/).

Comment: Só lembrando que para o formato brasileiro, vc tem que importar a línguagem... `angular-locale_pt-br.js`

Comment: Eu estou usando o Angular2 Ivan, voce poderia me dar um exemplo de como usar, eu nao consegui entender.

Comment: Você pode Utilizar a biblioteca [ngx-currency](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-currency) , ela é ótima para criação de máscaras, possui uma séria de configurações, com isso você pode customiza-la para atender as suas necessidades.